# Trying to add Select tag in Bootstrap Accordion header, But not able to stop propagation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accordion

I am trying to add Select tag in bootstrap accordion header, but when I try to select option from select Tag accordion toggle, As I add stop propagation to select by jQuery it doesn't work as expected.
Can we use Select in Accordion header ? If Yes, How can we handle this?

```
<div class="panel-group BDAccordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="panel-heading row" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." class="form-control col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-4">
            <div class="activitySelect">
                <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="1">2</option>
                </select>
                <label>Select Activity</label>
                <span class="error-message">
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>Please Choose   Option</span>
                      </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$("select").click(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is going to work but you can try to add also event.[stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) like this:

```
$("select").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

**Edit based on author's comments:**

First of all, I think you should add some info to your question such as the Bootstrap version. My advice is to update it to the 3.4.1v at least (and to format your code properly). By the way, here's a working fiddle based on your requests: http://jsfiddle.net/tooMuchLagWillKillYou/kbjq0d4t/6/

The issue in your code os that you put the select tag inside the anchor wich is responsible for the opening and closing of the accordion (the one with attribute data-toggle="collapse"). Basically you just need to place the select as a sibling of that anchor and you should be fine.

Comment: Tried this, Accordion Toggle issue is solved but select dropdown is getting toggle immediately after click

Comment: Okay, are you using Bootstrap 5 or a previous version?

Comment: Bootstrap 3.3.4